# Flipping UIButton while changing image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to change an image of a UIButton ,where the user hit the button, it will be flipped, and change to a new image ,this one does not flips ,but only change the image .

```
CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
  crossFade.duration = 1.0;
  crossFade.fromValue = (id)cell.imageView.image.CGImage;
  crossFade.toValue = (id)Cellimg.CGImage;
  crossFade.removedOnCompletion = NO;
  crossFade.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
  [cell.imageView.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"rotationY"];

  [cell setImage:Cellimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.50f];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:cell cache:NO];

// [baseBtn setTitle:newTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell setImage:Cellimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom button with an image view? Something like this-

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"path/to-image.png"];

UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); // flip the image view
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```